# How to stop Tomcat 9 being killed after .war deploy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment

I'm running Tomcat 9 on Linux server with Postgres datasource. I deploy my .war (developed with Java and Spring Boot) via Manager App and start the application via terminal (catalina run). It starts up correctly, Spring Context gets up and running, but after 10 seconds Tomcat gets killed (I see "killed" message in terminal, no trace in catalina logs).

When I started "clean" Tomcat 9 with (no .war files whatsoever) it ran correctly and showed its welcome page. However, when the .war is in place (/webapps), it won't stay alive.

This is my context.xml:

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://dedivirt1401.your-abc"
          username="abc" password="abc" maxTotal="50" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
</Context>
```

This is my server.xml:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

With this I expect Tomcat to get going but it stops on its own.

I'll appreciate help/ tips/ further questions.

Comment: Your best bet would be to check `catalina.out` and your app-specific log files. Most likely the server is not starting at all due to errors in the configuration/code/port issue or the OS is killing the service due to some reason. Check OS event logs as well.

Comment: @fiveelements Thanks for the tip. I can't access any detailed logs on the server as it's a hosted machine. Still, I could check catalina.out but there's no catalina.out in Tomcat filesystem. How did that happen?

Comment: I just got a message from server support their process watch kept killing my Tomcat.

Comment: Why the monitor (process watch) is killing the Tomcat? Is it due to the time taken to start up the Tomcat?

Comment: No, it’s just their policy to kill selected processes that seem suspicious.